# ios launch appstore from within my app causes my app to terminate

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store

I'm trying to take users of My App to the AppStore for several different functions - like Upgrade to Full Version, Rate/Review or simply View another App I've developed.  However, all of these are causing my App to Terminate when iTunes is launched on the device.  I'm using some simple code and 
have tried many combinations of URLs, all of which successfully get to where they are going.  Here are the behaviors:

- User clicks Rate App
- Code directs them to the web via:

  ```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:[[MyApp defaultApp] itunesLink]]];
  ```
- My App goes to the background, and my delegate's applicationDidEnterBackground is called successfully
- As iTunes is coming up, my App is terminated.  Happens whether I run via X-Code or on the device directly.
- When I quit out of the store and look at the running processes on the device, my App is still shown there.  I know it has been terminated from X-Code console, and when I try to restart it it starts fresh.

I've tried the itunesLink as either itms://itunes.apple.com/app/ or with http - all of which get to the correct end point.  If I use www.google.com it works fine and my App is NOT terminated, just sent to the background and the website is displayed OK.

Other points are that when I run via the simulator, the openURL call returns failure and doesn't open any URL.

Any insights as to why my App would be terminating?  It's acting like an iOS security feature or something which is shutting my App down, but I thought what I was doing was pretty standard stuff.

If anyone has seen anything similar, I'd really appreciate advice on the situation.

Comment: Note that the double-tap-home-button list of icons does not show *running apps*, but simply a history of apps that you launched. It does not tell you which apps are running.

Comment: Also, please don't go through the list hitting the "x" to "clean" your phone's memory. This does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app could be terminated for a number of reasons. The best thing is to look at the device console using Xcode's Organizer:

[image]

Your app may simply be terminated as a result of low memory notifications. As soon as it moves to the background and the app store launches (iTunes and the app store both use plenty of memory) it can be killed to free up memory. In this case you will set messages from "jetsam" like this:

```
<Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
<Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.yourapp[0x6337]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

You should use the Activity Monitor in Instruments to see how much memory your application is using. iOS will terminate the most memory-intensive applications first, so you should try to reduce your app's memory footprint.

Comment: Right-on.  In the console are messages for my App and another that are being killed at that time.  There are also kills for a few other processes:  

com.apple.accountsd, 
com.apple.timed, 
com.apple.mobile.assertion_agent, 
com.apple.crashreportcopymobile, 
com.apple.CommCenter, 
com.<myapp>.  
  And my app gets the kill -9 warning message you mentioned.

Comment: These errors happenned on iPod Touch (4G).  I just tested it on 2 other devices (iPad, iPad2) and it worked fine.  From what I've seen, they all should have 256MB.  One other thing is that I use the iPod Touch to view the old version of production downloaded App, and this caused me problems in testing my in-App purchase w/ Sandbox, etc. although I have deleted those Apps a while ago to focus on testing this release.